# Use TeX in Graphics object

Tags: latex

```
Graphics[Text[Style["Sqrt[a^2-b^2]", FontSize->25], {0,0}]]
```

yields:

[image]

but I want the nicer looking $\sqrt{a^2-b^2}$ instead of the ugly 
"Sqrt[a^2-b^2]". How?

Comment: Just leave out the quotes... `Graphics[Text[Style[Sqrt[a^2 - b^2], FontSize -> 25], {0, 0}]]` Use `HoldForm` if you don't want the quantities to evaluate.

Comment: Boy, do I feel stupid. Please make that an answer and I'll upvote/approve it.

Comment: no worries. This was just a simple mistake, so feel free to just delete the question :) We've all been there (you don't want to see my first mma notebook :D)

Comment: @rm-rf ooooh, do show that one,  will you?

Comment: As tempted as I am to "rm -rf" my answer, there's an offchance that it will help someone even stupider, so I'll keep it. @rm-rf please turn your comment into answer so I can upvote/approve, thanks.

Comment: @barrycarter Turns out, it was asked before and has a nice answer by Jens so I've marked it as a duplicate :)  You can read more there about changing the formatting for various symbols to fit your needs.